# Calling/Loading AS3 into AS2 and calling/loading AS2 into AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

Im really hoping that someone can help me! I have built a project in flash AS3 and have done everything that I needed to, however when attempting to build a game I couldn't get my head around writing global varriables in AS3 so I wrote them in AS2 thinking that I could do a simple code to call the SWF (game) file into the AS3 (main project) and then reverse the code in the game file to return to the main project when the menu button is selected. I have used this code:

```
stop()
var ld:Loader = new Loader()
ld.load(new URLRequest("game.swf"))
addChild(ld)
```

to call the SWF game file within the AS3 project. However when trying to reverse this within the AS2 file it wont open the AS3 project again?

Please can someone help me:( xxxx

Comment: Is it giving you any specific errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of AVM1 vs AVM2 (Adobe Virtual Machine)  AVM1 is AS2, AVM2 is AS3.  Unfortunately, you can't run AS3 in AS2, only AS2 in AS3.  And they don't communicate (I've tried).  The only thing you can do to get them to talk to each other is open up a local connection between the parent AS3 to the loaded AS2.  You won't get any visibility to root or global vars, just what you pass between via the localConnection.

Your better going with all AS3 and making a public static model class with the data you want to expose throughout the app instead.

Good luck.

Comment: This is going to sound so daft but how do I even go about doing all of that? The game is built... I just want it to open on the click of a button thats in the AS3 project (which it does already) and then link back to the main project from the game... is there a way around it... like within the project AS3 opening the game as a seperate window?

Comment: This is a decent tutorial - you're going to have to code something in both files to handle the communication then when the game is over, have the AS3 main get a signal from the AS2   http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/interface-between-two-files-using-the-localconnection-class/

Answer (score 0):

As Gone3D says, LocalConnection can be used to make calls between the main AS3 swf and a loaded AS2 swf, and I recommend using Grant Skinners SWFBridge for that:

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html